# ODBC Connection to DB2 Hangs

Tags: c#, odbc, db2

I have a function I use to send write queries to DB2 through ODBC, and it gets hung up in this function from time to time if I lose my connection to DB2. I am sending 60 as my timeout to the function, but it never times out. It just hangs up my thread indefinitely, and I'm not sure of a good way to force this function to give up.

```
public int WriteQuery(string query, string dbConnStr, int timeout)
{
    int rowsAffected = -1;
    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(dbConnStr);

    try
    {
            conn.Open();
            OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, conn);
            command.CommandTimeout = timeout;

            OdbcTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
            command.Transaction = trans;

            OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.UpdateCommand = command;

            rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            trans.Commit();
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }

        return rowsAffected;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea which statement is the one getting hung up? I don't see any kind of log statements, so I'm guessing you aren't sure unless you have seen this happen while walking the code in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways you are opening and closing the connection in same method. 
Try using :     OdbcConnection.ConnectionTimeout=60;

Hope this helps!